# Do I always need to specify my current working directory in Python?

Tags: python, regex, working-directory

I am working through the renameDates project in Automate the Boring stuff. It's supposed to match dates formated the American way and change them to the European format.

The thing I don't understand about this code is, how does it find the correct directory?

I can't find any code that sets the current working directory to the file I need it to work in, but the script seems written assuming the default current working directory is where it should work.

Is it something simple like, running the script from the file I want to search for regular expressions in will make Python set that file as the CWD?

```
#! python3
# renameDates.py - renames filenames with American MM-DD-YYYY date format
# to European DD-MM-YYYY.

import shutil, os, re

# Create a regex that matches files with the American date format.
datePattern=re.compile(r"""^(.*?) # all text before the date
    ((0|1)?\d)-                 # one or two digits for the month
    ((0|1|2|3)?\d)-             # on or two digits for the day
    ((19|20)\d\d)               #four digits for the year
    (.*?)$                      # all text after the date
    """, re.VERBOSE)
# loop over the files in the working directory.
for amerFilename in os.listdir('.'):
    mo=datePattern.search(amerFilename)

    # Skip files without a date.
    if mo==none:
        continue

    # Get the different parts of the filename.
    beforePart=mo.group(1)
    monthPart=mo.group(2)
    dayPart=mo.group(4)
    yearPart=mo.group(6)
    afterPart=mo.group(8)

# Form the European-style filename.
euroFilename=beforePart+dayPart+'-'+monthPart+'-'+yearPart+afterPart


# Get the full, absolute file paths.
absWorkingDir=os.path.abspath('.')
amerFilename=os.path.join(absWorkingDir, amerFilename)
euroFilename=os.path.join(absWorkingDir, euroFilename)

# Rename the files.
print('Renaming "%s" to "%s%...' % (amerFilename, euroFilename))
#shutil.move(amerFilename,euroFilename)  #uncomment after testing
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey do you run your code from Terminal or interpreter? It uses the current working directory. Normaly it's the directory where you have been before starting the script / python interpreter... You can check your current working directory with this code... Hope this helps you:

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

You can change the working directory with:

```
os.chdir(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a txt file with a date as a name like 11-11-2011 in your working directory and when you run the program you'll see the name has changed